# The usage of HitTestResult class in pygtk webkit

Tags: webkit, pygtk

I write a callback function for the context_menu popup through right-click in order to get the url of the link the mouse is pointing at, I know I can use WebKit.HitTestResult class to get the information from Gdk event(I assume it to the right-click event). However, the code below give me nothing.

I find the problem may be the incorrect usage of HitTestResult. But I can find little document talking about the usage of this class, could anyone help me with this?

```
def callback(self, widget, context_menu, hit_result_event, event):
    option = Gtk.ImageMenuItem('Do it')
    option.connect('activate', self.option_activate_cb)
    context_menu.append(option)
    option.show()

def option_activate_cb(self, image_menu_item):
    test = WebKit.HitTestResult()
    action = test.props.link-uri
    print action
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Basically, you have to use `HitTestResult.get_link_uri()`.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        view = WebKit2.WebView()
        view.load_uri('https://stackoverflow.com')
        view.connect('context-menu', self.on_context_menu)

        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.add(view)
        win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        win.show_all()

    def on_context_menu(self, webview, context_menu, event, hit_test_result):
        if hit_test_result.context_is_link():
            print(hit_test_result.get_link_uri())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
    Gtk.main()
```